# Click on Span withing table cell doesn't work- Protractor/Typescript

Tags: typescript, selenium, protractor

Click on Span Selement withing Grid cell is not working. I tried with actions and below code, both did not work. Please advise.

```
async SaveorCancelRow() {
    var table = this.component;
    var tbody = table.element(by.xpath(".//tbody"));
    var trs = tbody.all(by.tagName("tr")).get(1);

    //Click Save tr[@class='SearchResultItemView customGridHighlight']//td[3]
    await trs
      .element(by.xpath('.//td[3]//span[contains(@class, "save")]'))
      .click()
      .then(function() {
        browser.sleep(5000);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: provide HTML or your url

Comment: Can you provide more information on how it is "not working"? Was an Exception thrown, did the click do nothing, did a different element get clicked?

Comment: The click was supposed to save the record and no action happens when clicked. No exception was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Try below simplified code.

```
async SaveorCancelRow() {
    await this.component
             .element(by.css('tbody > tr.SearchResultItemView > td > span.save'))
             .click()

    return await browser.sleep(5000);
  }
}
```